# Use of zero_terms_query in elasticsearch dsl query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Can anyone explain zero_terms_query elasticsearch in detail, I went through elasticsearch documentation but I didn't understand properly

Comment: @Sudeesh is it clear now by my example ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets understand it by taking our own example, for that lets create an index using the english analyzer which would remove all the english stop words like `to be or not to be` [example given by Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-zero).

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "title" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "english"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index few sample document**

```
{
    "title": "sudeesh"
}

{
    "title": "to be or not to be"
}
```

Search query which removes all the stop words from query as we are using `match` query which applies the same `english` analyzer to search query.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "query": "to be or not to be",
                "operator": "and",
                "zero_terms_query": "all"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "72442818",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "to be or not to be"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "72442818",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "sudeesh"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Note, above search query returns both the document as we specified `"zero_terms_query": "all"` so it would be considered as `match_all` and returns all the documents.

If you remove `"zero_terms_query": "all"` than it would be considered as `none` default value mentioned in Elasticsearch documentation and you wouldn't get any search result **as there is no search term to search in the Elasticsearch.**

**this is especially useful when you are having all stop words in your query, and instead of 0 search results you want to return more search results.**

Comment: Good example, but you should also show how `none` works.

Comment: @Val just added info about none param as well :)